# Program gets stuck while acquiring data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, netty

I'm trying to develop a server/client program, the server is based on Netty. When the server gets data from a netty channel, I will query data from mongo. However, the channel will get stuck when it opened MongoDB's connection.
My code is simple is:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("account_id").is(accountId).and("account_type").is(accountType));
return seqKeyConvert.toProtoBuf(mongoTemplate.findOne(query, SeqKeyMongoEntity.class, collectionName));
```

And the server's log will be like this:

```
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            - Opened connection[connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:7530577}] to 100.75.53.176:5521
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-6] org.mongodb.driver.connection            - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:7530585}] to 100.75.53.176:5521
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-8] org.mongodb.driver.connection            - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:7530584}] to 100.75.53.176:5521
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-7] org.mongodb.driver.connection            - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:9, serverValue:7530586}] to 100.75.53.176:5521
```

The MongoDB configuration is like:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      manager:
        address: mongodb://100.75.53.176:5521,100.75.53.177:5521
        min-connections-per-host: 2
        max-connections-per-host: 100
        threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier: 10
        server-selection-timeout: 30000
        max-wait-time: 60000
        max-connection-idel-time: 28800000
        max-connection-life-time: 0
        connect-timeout: 30000
        socket-timeout: 0
        socket-keep-alive: false
        ssl-enabled: false
        ssl-invalid-host-name-allowed: false
        always-use-m-beans: false
        heartbeat-socket-timeout: 20000
        heartbeat-connect-timeout: 20000
        min-heartbeat-frequency: 500
        heartbeat-frequency: 10000
        local-threshold: 15
```

The channel will be stuck here and without any error throws. I have tried to test whether the MongoDB is ok and if I had set too few MongoDB connection number limit but without any finding. Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use `InitialzationBean` to set some variables that use MongoDB. It turns out this problem could be solved if I replace  InitialzationBean with `CommandLineRunner`.  Temporarily, I don't if some kind of race condition happens.